# I can change the password of one user from other user in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, permissions, lubuntu, security, system

I think its a bug or something I don't know.But I think this is serious problem that I can change the password of a administrator from other user.

Comment: Can you show the command that you used?

Comment: I have done that in settings>Details>Users not in terminal

Comment: Does the "other user" has admin/sudo rights?

Comment: More likely some file permissions that have been altered.

Comment: yes the other user is also a admin

Comment: so then there is no issue :) admin is suppose to be able to do that

Comment: You've tagged 14.04 & Lubuntu; Lubuntu 14.04 LTS reached EOL back in April-2017 (being a flavor it only had 3 years of LTS support; 5 applying to Ubuntu with Unity or Ubuntu server (no desktop).  Even Lubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL now, and only 14.04 ESM still has support but is off-topic here.

Comment: If you believe it's a bug - please report it.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   However note 14.04 bugs will likely just be closed due EOL (unless they impact Ubuntu 14.04 ESM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a sudo user, it's normal that you should be able to change other users' passwords.

Answer (score 0):

If you assigned particular permissions of administrator/root like /bin/passwd to perticular user, then from that user account using sudo command you can change the password of other user.